# select text on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

ive got this function and it works to select text on click

```
function select_text(ev) {
    if (this.createTextRange)
    {
        // This is for IE and Opera.
        range = this.createTextRange();
        range.moveEnd('character', this.value.length);
        range.select();
    }
    else if (this.setSelectionRange)
    {
        // This is for Mozilla and WebKit.
        this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);
    }
}
```

using:

```
$('input').click(select_text);
```

but i would like to select the text when a textfield is focused (its focused with jquery when i hit enter in another textfield).

i have tried this:

```
$('input#id').focus(select_text);
```

but it didnt work. could someone tell me how to write for this to work.

EDIT: the element that is going to be focused and selected is added with ajax! forgot to tell you that. ive tried this one but it didnt work:

```
$("#settings_view #password #new_password").live('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $("#settings_view #password #password_beam").html('Enter password:<input id="password_confirm" type="password" value="0123456789" />');
        $('input#password_confirm').focus(function (e) {
            var element = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                select_text.call(element, e);
            }, 0);
        });
    }
});
```

i also tried this for live:

```
$("#settings_view #password #new_password").live('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $("#settings_view #password #password_beam").html('Enter password:<input id="password_confirm" type="password" value="0123456789" />');
        $('input#password_confirm').live('focus', function (e) {
            var element = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                select_text.call(element, e);
            }, 0);
        });
    }
});
```

but it didnt work as well. some ideas?

Comment: Your selector is different for the focus statement - does it work with $('input').focus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code, and it worked for me: http://jsbin.com/esuwe

It worked without this change, but I would suggest you make this change as well if you always want the text to be selected when the box has focus via `tab`, `click`, or `focus()`

Right before your closing `}` of the `select_text` function, add `return false;`

```
function select_text(evt){
   ...

   return false;
}
```

And change `click` to `mouseup`.

```
$('input#id').mouseup(select_text).focus(select_text);
```

This keeps your click from resetting the selection to a specific spot in the textbox.

Comment: I might be mixing my preventDefault() with my stopPropagation(), but wouldn't returning false *prevent* the field from being focused at all when handling a focus event?

Comment: @Mike, it actually doesn't prevent the field from being focussed. I tested to be sure, but I only tested in Safari 4.

Answer (score 3):

The `focus` event happens before `click`, and the `click` event causes the selection to change.

Likewise, I think that `keyup` happens after `focus` when you use enter or tab to a field and causes the same side effect.

It's gross, I know, but I would handle it this way:

```
$('input').focus(function (e) {
    var element = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        select_text.call(element, e);
    }, 0);
});
```

This basically ensures that `select_text()` gets called after event handling for the entire focus change is completed.

Comment: You forgot to specify the interval.

Comment: I almost added the reason why to my answer... The second parameter of setTimeout is optional. I generally omit it as an idiom to indicate "please do this after the current execution stack unwinds". I'll make it 0 though, since this operation should happen immediately after.

Comment: hm, it didnt work. maybe i am doing wrong somewhere. forgot to tell you that the element is added with ajax. maybe thats why it doesnt work? read my updated post

Comment: `setTimeout` with a zero timeout is definitely the right way to do this. But why not just use the input's `select()` method if you're selecting the whole contents, instead of rolling your own selection code?

Comment: The `<input>` element you are trying to focus doesn't exist in your `keyup` event handler, so hitting enter at that point won't focus it. If your intent is to focus the field as soon as it is created, you need to call $('#password_confirm').focus(). Also, IDs are unique within a page, so you can shorten each of your jQuery selector to just the last ID you are using.